# System shuts down while rendering on blender

Tags: modeling, workflow, procedural

I am civil engineer currently working with sketchup and lumion for my drawings and rendering. I recently started using blender for modeling furniture and buildings. But while rendering on eevee and cycles shut my computer down. Currently have 8gb ram ,nvidea gt730 graphics, amd fx 8320. Should i stop using blender until my system is upgraded.or is there any other way i can finish my rendering even it took time.

Comment: System shutdown can be caused by a graphics driver crash, overheating or a PSU failing to deliver the required power. I would suggest you take a look at the event log to identify a potential cause. Installing the most recent graphics driver would also be recommend. If the crash is caused by a bug in the graphics driver, the issue may have been fixed in a newer version.

Comment: I will check into it & respond with result!!!

Comment: I things its heating problem..